# Disable some of the items in a drop down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I create a drop down and disable some (not all) of the options (items)? In the documentation it only describes how to disable all of them, or rather the entire drop down. That's not what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable specific options by passing `disable` attribute. Like in following code you can see some options are disabled.

```
<%= select_tag :country, options_for_select([['PK',{disabled: 'disabled'}],['IN'],['US',{disabled: 'disabled'}],['DE']]) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

[From API doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select)

> If you wish to specify disabled option tags, set selected to be a hash, with :disabled being either a value or array of values to be disabled.

```
options_for_select(["Free", "Basic", "Advanced", "Super Platinum"], disabled: "Super Platinum")
# => <option value="Free">Free</option>
# => <option value="Basic">Basic</option>
# => <option value="Advanced">Advanced</option>
# => <option value="Super Platinum" disabled="disabled">Super Platinum</option>
```